# Empty bar on the right side (Only on mobile or when browser is resized)

Tags: html, css, debugging, flexbox, display

I've just started learning CSS, so I made was trying to make a website.

It looks fine on pc. But there's this unwanted space on the right side when I resize the browser or load the website on my phone.

I think the problem lies in my CSS's navbar where I used display type "flex". But nothing I do fixes the problem.

Here's 2 screenshots I took.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hncy.jpg)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVc8z.png)

```css
body{margin: 0em; padding: 0em;
font-family: Calibri;
color: white;
background-color: black;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;}

.backgroundimage 
{height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1)),
url(https://rohitgejje.github.io/onepiecesample/images/onepiece.jpg);
z-index: -1;
background-size: cover;
}

/*--------------I think the problem lies here------------------------*/

.navbar {padding: 1em;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));}
.navbar>nav>ul>img {margin-right: 1em;
                    margin-left: 1em;}
.navbar>nav>ul {display: flex;}
.navbar>nav>ul>li {display: block;
                   margin: auto;}
.link {text-decoration: none;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-size: 1.25em;
        padding: 1em;}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.hugelogo {text-align: center;}




.news {text-align: center;}
.news>ul {display: flex;}
.news>ul>li {display:block; margin: auto;}


.about>h1 {text-align: center;}
.about>p {margin: 2em;}

.membershome {text-align: center;}
.membershome>ul {display: flex;}
.membershome>ul>li {display: block;
                    margin: auto;}

.galleryhome {text-align: center;}
.galleryhome>img {margin: 0.5em;}

.historyhome {text-align: center;
margin-top: 3rem;}


/* javascript starts here*/

.link:hover {background: radial-gradient( rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0)75%);
    border-radius: 10%;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Straw Hat Pirates</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="backgroundimage"></div>

    <header class="header">
    <div class="navbar">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/40" alt="logo" class="logonav">
                <li ><a href="" class="link">Home</a></li>
                <li ><a href="" class="link">Gallery</a></li>
                <li ><a href="" class="link">History</a></li>
                <li ><a href="" class="link">Login</a></li>  
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </header>


<section>

    <div class="hugelogo">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225" alt="logo" class="bigimghome">
    </div>
    
    <div class="news">
        <h3>News</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>update1</li>
            <li>update2</li>
            <li>update3</li>
            <li>update4</li>
            <li>update5</li>
            <li>update6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="about">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Ut dolor et excepturi quia temporibus vero nisi?
        Qui iste beatae dolorum explicabo? Velit quia ipsa voluptates
        ea nemo veritatis amet aperiam modi aliquid expedita assumenda
        neque, vel nihil, incidunt nam nesciunt illo consequatur eum
        possimus numquam fuga. Mollitia repellendus iure, soluta illum
        sapiente perspiciatis architecto beatae accusamus ad ut dolor
        at est delectus non dolores neque quasi, vel eligendi libero
        porro aliquam corporis veniam similique? Laudantium nulla quae
        architecto, facere cumque culpa excepturi placeat quia quidem
        ipsum. Veniam deleniti autem voluptas molestias suscipit
        reprehenderit possimus iure. Cupiditate a odit quidem. Nam
        molestiae odio quos esse iure deleniti voluptatum magnam
        rerum laudantium? Molestias ullam itaque, expedita
        blanditiis quasi asperiores dolores numquam similique error,
        laboriosam necessitatibus. Quos soluta officiis doloremque,
        harum quibusdam voluptas. Quia quisquam nulla laboriosam
        necessitatibus laudantium sunt recusandae corrupti tempore, nisi
        assumenda, accusantium, culpa quas? Dignissimos numquam reiciendis possimus
        facere.</p>


    </div>
 
    <div class="membershome">
        <h2>Members</h2>
            <ul>
                <li class="memberhome">member1</li>
                <li class="memberhome">member2</li>
                <li class="memberhome">member3</li>
                <li class="memberhome">member4</li>
                <li class="memberhome">member5</li>
                <li class="memberhome">member6</li>
            </ul>
        
    </div>

    <div class="galleryhome">
        <h2>Gallery</h2>
        <img src="https://www.unsplash.it/100/100" alt="img1">
        <img src="https://www.unsplash.it/100/100" alt="img2">
        <img src="https://www.unsplash.it/100/100" alt="img3">
        <img src="https://www.unsplash.it/100/100" alt="img4">
    </div>

    <div class="historyhome">
        <h2>History</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Suscipit cum perferendis dolorem magni laboriosam.
         Iste cumque, reiciendis distinctio sequi quidem dolore hic
         et repellendus deserunt ratione nisi velit provident?
         Laudantium.</p>
    </div>

</section>


<footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">IG</a></li>
                <li><a href="">FB</a></li>
                <li><a href="">SC</a></li>
                <li><a href="">WA</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

[3](https://github.com/RohitGejje/onepiecesample):[Github link](https://github.com/RohitGejje/onepiecesample)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's basically happening here is that your navbar is overflowing your body. While section takes only 100% width in body. So in this condition you have following option:

1. either add a scrollbar to navbar. (Quick fix)
2. add `flex-wrap:wrap;`.(navbar options will arrange themselves on second line, also a quick fix.)
3. Even expand your background with your navbar.(which I did in following code by setting body `width:auto;` which is 100% by default, now in mobile devices your website will look like just aa minimized version of pc site, Won't say its a good thing but if you want to make it work you have to work with media queries. which is to like write whole code)
4. Add a collapsing menu.(again media queries and code for creating collapsing navbar)

```css
body{margin: 0em; padding: 0em;
font-family: Calibri;
color: white;
background-color: black;
height: 100%;
width: auto;}

.backgroundimage 
{height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1)),
url(https://rohitgejje.github.io/onepiecesample/images/onepiece.jpg);
z-index: -1;
background-size: cover;
}

/*--------------I think the problem lies here------------------------*/

.navbar {padding: 1em;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));}
.navbar>nav>ul>img {margin-right: 1em;
                    margin-left: 1em;}
.navbar>nav>ul {display: flex;}
.navbar>nav>ul>li {display: block;
                   margin: auto;}
.link {text-decoration: none;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-size: 1.25em;
        padding: 1em;}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.hugelogo {text-align: center;}




.news {text-align: center;}
.news>ul {display: flex;}
.news>ul>li {display:block; margin: auto;}


.about>h1 {text-align: center;}
.about>p {margin: 2em;}

.membershome {text-align: center;}
.membershome>ul {display: flex;}
.membershome>ul>li {display: block;
                    margin: auto;}

.galleryhome {text-align: center;}
.galleryhome>img {margin: 0.5em;}

.historyhome {text-align: center;
margin-top: 3rem;}


/* javascript starts here*/

.link:hover {background: radial-gradient( rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0)75%);
    border-radius: 10%;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Straw Hat Pirates</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="backgroundimage"></div>

    <header class="header">
    <div class="navbar">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/40" alt="logo" class="logonav">
                <li ><a href="" class="link">Home</a></li>
                <li ><a href="" class="link">Gallery</a></li>
                <li ><a href="" class="link">History</a></li>
                <li ><a href="" class="link">Login</a></li>  
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </header>


<section>

    <div class="hugelogo">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225" alt="logo" class="bigimghome">
    </div>
    
    <div class="news">
        <h3>News</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>update1</li>
            <li>update2</li>
            <li>update3</li>
            <li>update4</li>
            <li>update5</li>
            <li>update6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="about">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Ut dolor et excepturi quia temporibus vero nisi?
        Qui iste beatae dolorum explicabo? Velit quia ipsa voluptates
        ea nemo veritatis amet aperiam modi aliquid expedita assumenda
        neque, vel nihil, incidunt nam nesciunt illo consequatur eum
        possimus numquam fuga. Mollitia repellendus iure, soluta illum
        sapiente perspiciatis architecto beatae accusamus ad ut dolor
        at est delectus non dolores neque quasi, vel eligendi libero
        porro aliquam corporis veniam similique? Laudantium nulla quae
        architecto, facere cumque culpa excepturi placeat quia quidem
        ipsum. Veniam deleniti autem voluptas molestias suscipit
        reprehenderit possimus iure. Cupiditate a odit quidem. Nam
        molestiae odio quos esse iure deleniti voluptatum magnam
        rerum laudantium? Molestias ullam itaque, expedita
        blanditiis quasi asperiores dolores numquam similique error,
        laboriosam necessitatibus. Quos soluta officiis doloremque,
        harum quibusdam voluptas. Quia quisquam nulla laboriosam
        necessitatibus laudantium sunt recusandae corrupti tempore, nisi
        assumenda, accusantium, culpa quas? Dignissimos numquam reiciendis possimus
        facere.</p>


    </div>
 
    <div class="membershome">
        <h2>Members</h2>
            <ul>
                <li class="memberhome">member1</li>
                <li class="memberhome">member2</li>
                <li class="memberhome">member3</li>
                <li class="memberhome">member4</li>
                <li class="memberhome">member5</li>
                <li class="memberhome">member6</li>
            </ul>
        
    </div>

    <div class="galleryhome">
        <h2>Gallery</h2>
        <img src="https://www.unsplash.it/100/100" alt="img1">
        <img src="https://www.unsplash.it/100/100" alt="img2">
        <img src="https://www.unsplash.it/100/100" alt="img3">
        <img src="https://www.unsplash.it/100/100" alt="img4">
    </div>

    <div class="historyhome">
        <h2>History</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Suscipit cum perferendis dolorem magni laboriosam.
         Iste cumque, reiciendis distinctio sequi quidem dolore hic
         et repellendus deserunt ratione nisi velit provident?
         Laudantium.</p>
    </div>

</section>


<footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">IG</a></li>
                <li><a href="">FB</a></li>
                <li><a href="">SC</a></li>
                <li><a href="">WA</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ik I'm not supposed to say it but, Thank You!

Comment: @RohitGejje Glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer if you found it helpful.